# SharePoint 2007 datasheet view not working after install of Microsoft Office 2013

Tags: 2007, view

Data sheet view worked in MS Office 2010/IE8 but since I was upgraded to MS Office 2013/IE10 data sheet view does not work.

I do not have a option to go back to MS Office 2010/IE8.
SharePoint 2007 is going to get upgraded but that is not for another month.

ActiveX is enabled.
Attempted to use compatibility view and that did not work.
Added site to trusted site list.
Made sure MS Access 2013 was installed on my computer.

Any help would be appreciated?

Comment: I don't have a resolution for you, but this should work. I am using Office 2013 and IE 11 and just checked to ensure I didn't have the same issue. Have you tried resetting IE back to defaults?

Comment: I was so hoping that would work but nada.  Still have the same problem but thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

My issue somehow resolved itself but here is what I did in case someone else is still having this problem.

- Reset IE 10 back to defaults.
- Made sure MS Access 2013 was installed.
- Used repair option from Control Panel for MS Office 2013
- Rebooted PC

Now the above did happen in order but over several days as I was trying to figure out how to solve this.

Answer (score 2):

Again, in case anyone else encounters this issue....

I've just found the same problem having un-installed Office 2007 from my work machine. I found this page [Describing the problem](http://community.rightpoint.com/blogs/viewpoint/archive/2012/12/04/using-sharepoint-2010-dataview-with-windows-8-and-or-office-2013.aspx) and a link to a [Microsoft Driver](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23734) for '2007 Office System Driver: Data Connectivity Components' which fixed the issue without needing any repairs or restarts.

Answer (score 0):

Try checking compatibility settings in IE and adding the site collection to the compatibility websites (I also selected "display intranet sites in compatibility view" and "use Microsoft compatibility lists".  Once I completed this I was able to see that datasheet view again.