# 2007 - Unable to mark checkboxes as checked in datasheet view

Tags: 2007, view

I'm using an old SharePoint 2007.

In a new PC (Windows 10) I've noticed that datasheet view was not available.

I've searched and found this question [SharePoint 2007 datasheet view not working after install of Microsoft Office 2013](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/93820/sharepoint-2007-datasheet-view-not-working-after-install-of-microsoft-office-201) , then I installed the suggested Microsoft Driver.

Datasheet view worked fine after the installation of the driver, but the user was not able to mark checkboxes as checked. The user can edit text fields, but is impossible to change checkboxes status.

I've added the site to "Intranet sites" (also tried with "Trusted Sites") and enabled the compatibility view in Internet Explorer, but nothing helped me.

Any suggestion?

Comment: What version of IE are you using?

Comment: @lazoDev Internet Explorer 11

Comment: Try opening up the datasheet view and use IE DEV Toolbar to switch the Doc Type to IE 8 and see if that works for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue solved.

I repaired Microsoft Office 2016.